# How can I use RegEx to find a term, if the term is broken by a new-line in the searched text

Tags: c#, .net, regex, whitespace

Say I'm searching for "applicants", and as things have before happened to me, I receive a text file like this:

```
We have considered the applica
nt's experience and qualification, 
and wish to grant him an interview.
```

Now I still want my RegEx to return a match at index 23 of the whole word "applicant", and I want to tell the user the partial match starts on line *m* and column *n*. How can I achieve this?

A rather tedious solution I have in mind is to insert a special marker-character before each match, each time incrementuing the indices of the remaining matches. Then repeat the search on a line by line basis and look for the marker followed by the first char of the search term.

Comment: Remove all the linebreaks with `.Replace("\r\n", string.Empty)` and  search as usual.

Comment: I want to tell the user which line the match starts on.

Comment: That is not mentioned in the question. How are you processing the file? Note that a regex will never tell you what "line" it finds a match on.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Apologies. It is now. I'm trying to figure a regex where a line break or tab is allowed anywhere within the search term.

Comment: The somewhat uglier alternative is to replace your search string. `new Regex(Regex.Replace("applicant", "(?<=.)(?=.)", "\\r?\\n?"))`

Comment: Can you please just explain that a little bit. What is a *Zero-width positive lookbehind assertion*?

Comment: Your mean `(?<=.)(?=.)`? That matches any position between two characters, in order to insert `\r?\n?` into the string. What zero width assertions themselves are is explained at length over here http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert `[\t\r\n]*` (matches zero or more chars from the defined set) in between each character in the search word. Then, split the  part of the text starting from 0 index to the `match.Index` with a regex matching linebreaks (`@"\r?\n|\r"`) and there you go:

```
var text = "Morelines\n\nWe have considered the applica\t\r\nnt's experience and qualification, \nand wish to grant him an interview.";
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Our text:\n{0}\n---------", text));
var search = "applicant";
var pattern = string.Join(@"[\t\r\n]*", search.ToCharArray());
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Our pattern: {0}\n----------", pattern));
var result = Regex.Match(text, pattern);
if (result.Success) {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Match: {0} at {1}\n----------", result.Value, result.Index));
    var lineNo = Regex.Split(text.Substring(0, result.Index), @"\r?\n|\r").GetLength(0);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Line No: {0}", lineNo));
}
```

See the [online C# demo](http://ideone.com/QnTO9C)

Output:

```
Our text:
Morelines

We have considered the applica  
nt's experience and qualification, 
and wish to grant him an interview.
---------
Our pattern: a[\t\r\n]*p[\t\r\n]*p[\t\r\n]*l[\t\r\n]*i[\t\r\n]*c[\t\r\n]*a[\t\r\n]*n[\t\r\n]*t
----------
Match: applica  
nt at 34
----------
Line No: 3
```

Comment: Looks good, trying it now. Just curious as to your line-break regex: Why not `\r?\n?`? If there is no `\n` it should still match `\r`, yet you include a lone `\r` as a second option.

Comment: `\r?\n?` matches an empty string, I do not want to match an empty string. `\r?\n` matches Windows and Unix linebreaks and `\r` matches Mac OS linebreaks. Summing up: `\r?\n|\r`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line breaks to "".

Comment: Thanks, @Dexiobn, but please see my comments in the OP.

Comment: Replace the line breaks to (char)2 or (char)255 or any other special char, this is a good separator char and you can count/match them.

Comment: My conundrum is how to allow for (char)2 or char(255) anywhere in my search term?

Comment: a[\w_]+ would match applica_nt .

Comment: It would only match that, as if I know the the line break is the 3rd from last char.  @Tomalak's voodoo: `Regex.Replace("applicant", "(?<=.)(?=.)", "\\r?\\n?")` seems like it might do the trick, because it inserts a line-break pattern between each character in the search term.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty way :

```
applica\n?nt
```

If you dont know where could the line break appear then add it between every characteres.

Comment: It would have to be more like "applica[\n|\r|\n\r]*nt. I don't know whether line endings are 1 or 2 chars, and whether they exist at all.

Comment: True ^^  your solution is even better if there are several linefeed