# Finding a line in the file where a specific string begins?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I came up with an issue finding the index of the line where a specific string (sentence) begins. May it seem easy, but when it comes to multi-line sentence, things do not get that easy.

To illustrate this, presume, **this a text file:**

```
1. The very first sentence. Second
2. sentence (multi-line).
```

So, let's say I have second sentence assigned to a **string:**

```
string sentence = "Second sentence (multi-line)."
```

And what I want to do is to find the index of a line where my sentence begins. In this case, **output should be equals 1.**

**My code so far:**

```
    static int GetSentenceLocation(string fileName, string sentence)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@fileName);
        string[] words = sentence.TrimStart().Split(' ');
        int location = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(lines[i], words[0]))
            {
                location = i;
            }
        }
        return ++location;
    }
```

But it does not work properly since the same word may repeat in other sentences.
Any ideas on how to overcome the issue? :)

Comment: can you post full string of sentence parameter example? how are you represent ing new line characters? is it /n or /r/n ?

Comment: Go through the file line by line, add all text to a string until a period is encountered, remember at which line the collecting started, add that info to a `Dictionary<int, string>` using `.Add(line, text)`, and then start over, until all text is processed. Then search through the Dictionary. Or you could even skip the Dictionary if you only need the first result.

Comment: You can just parse all the text into one single string and search your substring there. When you have found your substring all you have to do is get the number of `\n`-characters before this string.

Comment: You need to define what is a sentence. Do you want to find the starting line of a match ignoring whitespace differences? Do we have to only try matching at the beginning of a sentence? Do you have any other sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem may be very complicated, but for your test case, something like this may work. You just have to join all the rows in one string variable. Then look for the index of the sentence and finally, look in what line does that index fall. 
Something like this:

```
static int GetSentenceLocation()
{
    string[] lines = new string[2];
    lines[0] = "The very first sentence. Second";
    lines[1] = "sentence (multi-line).";

    string sentence = "Second sentence (multi-line).";

    string alltext = string.Join(" ", lines);

    int index = alltext.IndexOf(sentence);

    int charCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
    {
        charCount += lines[i].Length;
        if (charCount > index)
            return i + 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Of course this code can be optimized, but i hope you get the idea.

Comment: It did work out :) I adjusted the algorithm to be more versatile. Truly, thank you for helping me out! ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.  How do you define a "sentence" in such a way that your code can figure it out?  For instance, how many sentences do you see here:  "Do you think A.I. is real, i.e. can a computer really think like a human?"  There are a handful of periods.  Whereas a human can distinguish the sentence, a computer cannot.

**EDIT:**

Okay, it seems like I need a better example to prove this.  Given the following two human-discernible sentences:

> You should find a good primary care doctor e.g. Dr. Johnson.   
> Dr. 
>   Johnson is a really good doctor.

What if I wanted to figure out what line the sentence that starts with "Dr. Johnson" is on?  A human can see that the "real" sentence that starts with "Dr. Johnson" is on line #2.  However, a computer might say "I see a period after "e.g." followed by a space followed by a capital letter, and it matches my search text.  So it's line #1.

Comment: This is possible with a regular expression. I already answered a very similar question some time ago. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40399352/how-can-i-use-regex-to-find-a-term-if-the-term-is-broken-by-a-new-line-in-the-s/40405234#40405234). Perhaps, the current question can be closed as a dupe.

Comment: No, it's not.  Please provide evidence to prove it if you think so.

Comment: It would be **easy** to go through the file line by line, add all text to a string until a period is encountered, remember at which line we started collecting, add that to a `Dictionary<int, string>` using `.Add(line, text)`, and then start over, until all text is processed. And then search through the Dictionary. Or you could even skip the Dictionary if you only need the first result. So definitely NOT impossible.

Comment: @PeterB So what happens when you encounter the period after `i.e.`.  Is the next word the start of a sentence?

Comment: Yeah, seems fairly straightforward to choose a " . " as a delimiter to define a sentence, then if it encounters a new line ("\r\n" or whatever) it just concatenates with the next line, and makes a note the start of the sentence was the previous line. Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: I based my algo on the example provided, it seems that this school exercise was not using abbreviations... But good *point* (no pun intended).

Comment: @J.McCabe So to break my single sentence example on the periods, it would result in 5 separate sentences.  The last sentence doesn't even end with a period, it ends with a question mark.

Comment: @rory.ap Well, obviously, depending upon the expected contents of the text file, you may or may not need to store a stricter list of what constitutes an end-of-sentence delimiter, right? But that should be a fairly quick exercise. Especially if you know your file only contains certain types of characters.

Comment: I think you may be over thinking this question. OP just have the sentence to search, so you don't have to define "what is a sentence", just looking for the same characters in the same order in a string,as i explain in my answer...

Comment: @rory.ap you seem to be assuming this must work for every possible type of character composition on the planet. It depends on the contents of the text file. If you're not expecting to have the abbreviations you mentioned, or you do expect them and can identify them, your issue is irrelevent.

Comment: @J.McCabe -- If you don't want to write a robust algorithm, then sure, use your approach.  I wouldn't want to purchase any software that you've written though.  Identify the abbreviations?  Really?  Every single one?  There are probably hundreds of thousands of abbreviations, maybe millions.  What about in the future when new abbreviations are created?  That's nonsense.

Comment: The abbreviations may not be very difficult to identify. if a "sentence" (defined as all the characters in between dots) has only 1 character, that's an abbreviation. You may have to refine this idea, but you see what i mean

Comment: @Pikoh Of course. It depends upon how the text file was generated, if the input data to the file was checked/filtered on input, whether any abbreviations are expected, and so on. But to say it's impossible is ludicrous.

Comment: The point I'm trying to make here is that I could find examples all day long.  You simply cannot write a robust **reliable** algorithm that does this 100% of the time.  Don't you want to write code that works 100% of the time?  I know it's not humanly possible to do so -- write completely-bug-free code, but to go into something *knowing* that it's a fruitless endeavor is foolhardy.

Comment: As i have told before, i think you are going a lot more deeper than the OP question pretended.Just look at the title _Finding a line in the file where a specific string begins_. Sentences has nothing to do with it i think :)

Comment: @J.McCabe -- well you can take or leave it.  I'm moving on.  In my experience, this is a foolish task to take on.  Sure, if I had years to commit to this algorithm, I could come up with an algorithm that *maybe* works 100% of the time, but given the continual introduction of new Unicode characters, the continual changes to language...for this exercise, it's "not possible".

Comment: @Pikoh I think, though may be wrong, that the OP wasn't saying he was checking for a specific string (eg, the string "sentence") and checking which line it's in. I think he was looking for the line in which the sentence begins. Which means you must define a sentence

Comment: @J.McCabe you may be right. but in OP example, it's using a string with the sentence to search for. But,as he has not explained anything after throwing the question, we can't be sure :)

Comment: Although there are two "Dr. Johnson" in the above sample, if the search text is "Dr. Johnson is a really good doctor.", you will only find the second instance thus the text start on the second line. Thus in practice, it should not be much of a problem and if it was, there you would probably want to find all possible matches anyway. And if one also use (some) ponctuations to identify possible start of a sentence, then you still have less chance to find the wrong text.

Answer (score 0):

As of my comment simply put the whole file into a string and remove the searchstring from it. Now count the number of line-breaks in the remaining string and you´re done:

```
var allLines = String.Join("", File.ReadAllLines(fileName));
var index = allLines.IndexOf("The very first sentence. Second\nsentence (multi-line).");
var tmp = allLines.Substring(0, index);
var result = tmp.Count(x => x == '\n');
```